# How do you merge two files in Git?

Tags: git, github, merge, repository

So, I created ***fileA*** and then pushed it onto github. Then, locally I changed the name to ***fileB*** and continued adding more codes into it.

I realized that after I push it onto github. It is now being seen as two separate files. My question is how do I merge the 2 files back together?

Comment: Are there also changes to fileA from github ?

Comment: Note that merging requires *three versions* of *one file*. These three versions can have any file names you like, when using `git merge-file`, but one of the three versions is the *base* version and the remaining two are the versions made from the base. The merge operation combines the two changes-with-respect-to-base.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways how to solve this issue.

Github command line provides you with a command:

- git merge-file fileA fileB

Otherwise, you can also merge them locally and push your branch into the main.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know this command existed! Thank you!